# RegEx differences

Tags: php, regex

Can someone please tell me the difference exactly between these 2 RegEx's?

```
'/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/'
```

and

```
'~[^A-Za-z0-9_]~'
```

Also, is there a syntax error for the space within the first Regex?  Thinking it needs to be like this:  `/\s` to be escaped properly.

Basically, I need a RegEx that only uses English A-Z, a-z, 0-9, and underscores only!  Everything else will need to be replaced with an empty string `''`.  So, I know I need preg_replace to do this with, but Which RegEx is better to use, and why?

Thanks many guys!

Comment: `\s` means `any whitespace character`, so you will want to use the second one. I have no idea as to which one is better concerning `/` and `~`.

Comment: So, using the first one will let whitespace characters slip through than right?

Comment: Am interested in the differences between the `~` and `/` also.  What is the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first character of the PCRE pattern string is a delimiter used to mark the end of the regular expression and the start of the [modifier characters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php). The choice is arbitrary; you can use `'/'` or `'~'` or another character, but note that if you need the character in the expression part, then you will need to escape it.

In a character class, `\s` means any space character. Thus `'/[^a-zA-Z0-9\\s]/'` matches one character *not* in the set A-Z, a-z, 0-9, and space characters. `'~[^A-Za-z0-9_]~'` matches one character *not* in the set A-Z, a-z, 0-9, and underscore (`'_'`).

One pattern string that meets your requirements is `'~[^A-Za-z0-9_]+~s'`:

```
<?php
$str = <<<STR
test_

one

two Three  45
STR;

echo preg_replace('~[^A-Za-z0-9_]+~s', '', $str);
```

which outputs:

```
test_onetwoThree45
```

http://codepad.org/Ycl1WvR8

Comment: What does the `+~s` at the end of your RegEx do exactly?

Comment: @SoLoGHoST: The regular expression is `[^A-Za-z0-9_]+`. `+` means "match the previous thing one or more times greedily". In this case, the "previous thing" is the  negative class `[^A-Za-z0-9_]`. `s` is a modifier character. It means "a dot metacharacter in the [expression] matches all characters, including newlines". It's not necessary in this case because a negative class always includes newlines (unless \n is listed). However, I like to include it whenever I want a regular expression to match multiple lines of text to prevent problems later on if I change it to include a `.` metacharacter.

Answer (score 2):

The `^` inside your regex means NOT...and that is

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9]
```

means the string have not to have a-z, A-Z and 0-9 so if you want to replace all the chars which are not in those ranges (include the '_'), you have to use this statement:

$cleanString = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_]/', '', $theString);